# Images downloaded from Google Drive lose their description

Tags: google-drive

If you add descriptions to images in Google Drive and then download those images, the descriptions are not attached anywhere in the image properties/metadata. Is there a way prevent this or are the descriptions stored externally to the image, as opposed to as metadata (IPTC, XMP, EXIF)?

Comment: I found this article with a chart which makes Google+ look really good. Unfortunately I don't think you can actually edit IPTC descriptions or title or keywords in Google+.

Comment: Alex removed a part of my post that talked about other online photo services, but anyway, I would like to know of a service that can actually edit and preserve metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive user interface doesn't have a built-in way to view or edit IPTC, XMP, EXIF metadata. As far as I know, Drive SDK has method to get the image metadata but not to change it.

**References**
[Drive Help](http://support.google.com/drive)
[Files - Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)